# Is the "to" in "Let's meet from 4 _to_ five", 到？

Tags: word-choice

A simple question, trying to say, let's have a lesson from 4 to 5 -- want to make sure that "to" is indeed 到.

Comment: A simple answer: yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

到 is OK. You could also use 至. 到 is more colloquial. In many cases they are interchangeable, for example: 从古到今/从古至今（from ancient times to the present）, 直到此刻/直至此刻（up to now）. But you could only say 自始至终（from the beginning to the end），从这到那（from here to there） because 自始至终 and 从这到那 are kinda like set phrases.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right.

The general meaning of "到" in Chinese is the same as "to" in "from...to", and also it has the meaning of arrival.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.

> 我们上课从四点到五点. Let's have a lesson from 4 P.M. to 5P.M .

Answer (score -1):

至 is more formal.
Both are ok.